# Bad state: no element, I want to fetch object from my class file

Tags: flutter, dart

Errors are thrown by firstwhere method which can be called on Lists

I have a class named Products that holds objects of product(which is model of how each product is) every product object has its own unique id generated using `DateTime.now.toString()`

Now here I have 2 paths,
**first: ** if I press the update button on my app i will be updating the product already there in my list which i can find using `_productList.firstWhere` and it will return me my product without any error

option 2
I add a new product with new id, now i have to check where this id product is already there in my list or not

**I am using this logic to check whether the id String is available in my list of products or not**

```
bool hasId(String prod_id) {
    late bool result;
    
    _items.firstWhere((element) {
      if (element.id == prod_id) {
        result = true;
      }
      if (element.id != prod_id) {
        result = false;
      }
        return result;
    });
    return result;
  }
```

**PROBLEM HERE IS**
it throws error when it don't find any object with this test

**ERROR IS**

```
The following StateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Bad state: No element
```

**I WANT TO KNOW THAT IT COULDNT FIND ANY OBJECT WITH THAT ID WITHOUT THROWING AN ERROR**

****NOTE THAT:****
_ITEMS HOLD OBJECTS WHICH HAVE ID, ALSO I WANT TO RETURN STRING
I TRIED, orElse: on firstWhere but it wants an object to be returned which I don't have

Answer (score 0):

_item.firstWhere() will return your item Model not boolean.
So, you may do as the following:

```dart
List<Product?> _products = [
    Product(id: '123', name: 'P1'),
    Product(id: '124', name: 'P2'),
];

bool hasId(String productId) {
    bool isExist = false;
    Product? product = _products.firstWhere((product) => product?.id == productId, orElse: () => null);
    if (product != null) {
      isExist = true;
    }
    return isExist;
}
```